# Regex for simple custom matching

Tags: regex

I need to have a regex it should match strings like following

```
aaaa
bbbbb
aaabbb
ababaab
bbbaaaa
```

and it should not match

```
aaaacaaaac
abc
abababacababa
bbbaaaac
```

I tried [ab] but this is not satisfying my requirements

Comment: Perhaps `^[ab]+$`

Comment: Or `^[ab]*$` if an empty string should also match.

Comment: Or try this `^[^c]+$`